# Onchange event in one XHTML page should be reflected in another XHTML page whats the correct way to do it.

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml

While including multiple XHTML page into one page

that is i have separate XHTML pages for menu,filter bar, top-header etc.. 
i m including them in one page called the MAIN.XHTML using ui:include tags

When a user changes values in the FILTER BAR of the FILTER.XHTML which is a separate XHTML page i want it to trigger a javascript function in MAIN.XHTML is this possible? if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Server side it is initially separate files but for serverside jsf and client side html it becomes one page. So all normal rules apply

Answer (score -2):

if you are using primefaces try using layouts,
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/layout/element.xhtml

you can build a fullpage layout then every layout unit calling different xhtml 
ie.

`<p:layoutUnit position="south" size="XX">
 <ui:include src="yourweb.xhtml"/>
</p:layoutUnit>`

then you use javascripts on each xhtml